# Any well-known approach to kick-off a web site in order for output caching to take place

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, performance, caching, web-applications

Let's assume that we have web site which runs on `IIS 7.5` and built with `ASP.NET MVC 3`. Also assume that this website has lots of unique pages for products and all of that pages is being cached for 24 hours in memory. There are other pages also which benefits from output caching.

Everything is fine till here. As soon as we deploy a new update into IIS, the pool is recycled and all of the cache is gone.

So, I consider building a console app which basically do one thing: go and consume every single page for the website.

Is this the way of doing that sort of thing? Is there any known method for that?

Comment: Why? Is the initial construction of a page that expensive that you want to cache it up front?

Comment: @rene yes, I am doing some database call up front for each product page so I want them to be cached as soon as I go to production.

Comment: I would spend my development effort on solving the botllenecks. For achieving what you want: take a look at wget http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/ maybe combine it with a commandscript and a list productid to get to specific pages

Comment: Surely when your cache drops out after 24 hours your next client will have to suffer the delay of getting a 'fresh' page anyway? No?

Comment: @K.Bob right but at least at first, there will be no suffer. I am also thinning to schedule this app so that my console app only suffers.

Comment: @rene I have a sitemap so the page links are no problem.

Comment: You'd have to be very careful about timing a schedule, one second too early and you'll get the cached response, one second too late and one of your clients will have taken the hit already and you'll get the new cached response.

Comment: @K.Bob yep, you got that right. I shouldn't go for this option. I consider out of process distributed cache options after Jakob's answer.

Comment: A way to get around the timing difficulty that @K.Bob has raised is to add a route to your website to reset the cache. I am looking at doing exactly what tugberk is talking about, but all of our cache objects are inserted with a keystone dependency, so we can clear them out programmatically. 

If you have a url route (you can add authorization) you can hit that route first to clear out the cache, and then loop through all your products to cache them. That's the idea I'm going to work on anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to address this issue. A few:

1. Pre-cache the data in SQL Server by issuing queries that read the required tables into RAM. Of course, you need enough RAM for the tables to fit. You can run the task from SQL Agent at a specific time.
2. Add a distributed caching middle tier, such as AppFabric (warning: potential headaches)
3. Use .NET 4.0 app auto-start and a cache pre-warming class
4. Use Application_Start() in global.asax
5. Start a background thread in your app that reads in the required data structures
6. Use ASP.NET object caching in addition to output caching, and pre-load the object cache using one of the methods above
7. In addition to or instead of issuing DB queries from your background thread or cache warmer, use the WebRequest class to fetch a copy of each page in your app, which will cause it to be loaded in the output cache
8. Set your AppPool to recycle at a specific time of day, and have a Windows Scheduled Task that runs at a specific time after that, which causes the pages to be loaded, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Microsofts' [AppFabric](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/ee695849), it's a distributed cache and the cached elements will survive when the site is recycled.

Comment: I also thought about that. I will check that out in depth.

Comment: do you know that if I can only use Windows Azure AppFabric?

Comment: There are other options, MemCached and Redis comes to mind, but I've never tried those.

Comment: this article looks promising and up to date: http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/asp.net-mvc-output-caching-with-windows-appfabric-cache. What do you think?

Comment: It looks interesting. And AppFabric is actually quite easy to implement, once you get used to the Powershell commands required to configure it.

Comment: Is it still CTP? and does MSFT continue to develop it?

Comment: AFAIK it's out of CTP. And I haven't heard anything to indicate M$ wouldn't continue to work on it...

Answer (score 0):

In .NET 4.0, Output cache is extensible. Check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg650661.aspx